# SQLite: Sorting data in two columns

Tags: sqlite

Beginner question to SQLite.

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE raw (ID int, t int, VarID Int,  val float)
INSERT INTO raw VALUES (1, 77 , 1,177)
INSERT INTO raw VALUES (2, 77 , 2,277)
INSERT INTO raw VALUES (3, 12 , 1,112)
INSERT INTO raw VALUES (4, 12 , 2,212)
INSERT INTO raw VALUES (5, 55 , 2,255)
```

Here `t`is a timestamp, `VarID` indicates the to which variable the subsequent `val` belongs.

Now I want to get an view in which all variables are in separate columns, like:

```
t   var1   var2
77  177    277
12  112    212
55  None    255
```

**For reference only:**

This is the reverse question to [Reorganising Data in SQLLIte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581215/reorganising-data-in-sqllite))

Some code I've tried w/o getting the desired result

```
CREATE VIEW  view1 
AS SELECT 
t,
(SELECT val FROM raw WHERE VarID=1) as var1,
(SELECT val FROM raw WHERE VarID=2) as var2
FROM raw as r;
```

Comment: Have you tried any code yourself to accomplish this task?

Comment: Yes of course: I only got to the code `CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT  t, (SELECT val FROM r WHERE r.VarID=1) as var1, (SELECT val FROM r WHERE r.VarID=2) as var2, FROM raw as r;`which doesn't show the desired behaviour (for reason i understand).

Comment: Could you please include the code from your comment, formatted in your question?

Comment: done. incl. small adaptations form comment code, to make it executables

Comment: I think you can group by t and then transposing the table
[this question might be usful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table)

Comment: Thanks for the hint 'grouping'. I found a feasible solution as shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of  Avi Gurfinkel (grouping) I came up with the following solution. Is this the best way or are there more elegant ways to do this?

```
CREATE VIEW view1 
AS SELECT 
t,
(SELECT  val FROM raw WHERE (varID=1 and r.t=raw.t)) as var1,
(SELECT  val FROM raw WHERE (varID=2 and r.t=raw.t)) as var2
FROM raw as r
GROUP BY t;
```

Comment: The GROUP BY clauses in the subqueries are superfluous (if the combination `varID`/`t` is unique).